# Increase volume on multiple files

Tags: ffmpeg

Let say I have a couple of hundreds mp3 files. How do I increase volume in all of them with ffmpeg?

This is for single file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a "volume=1.5" output.mp3
```

And what about multiple files with one command?

Comment: Define your problem with more detail: you want one output file for each input file? Best to use a script to call ffmpeg once for each file. You want multiple inputs to be concatenated into one output? Well, that's something to do with ffmpeg, sure.

Comment: I was imagining something like this would work:
ffmpeg -i %03d.mp3 -filter:a "volume=1.5" boosted%03d.mp3
apparently not.

Comment: Right: that won't work. You only get one output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write a loop in whatever scripting language your shell uses to call ffmpeg for each file.

e.g. for bash:

```
mkdir louder
for f in *.mp3
do
  ffmpeg -i $f -filter:a "volume=1.5" louder/$f
done
```

or in Windows batch (untested):

```
FOR %%F IN (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg -i %%F -filter:a "volume=1.5" louder/%%F
```

And see https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html

Comment: Is it gonna wait till every task completed or will just run task for every file in directory and my pc will freeze? Also bash is linux only? What can you recommend for windows?

Comment: You can script in window shell (command.exe). I'll add an example.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users, type in command line interface:

```
for %i in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -filter:a "volume=1.5" "%~ni-150percent.mp3"
```

Comment: Is this for Microsoft Windows?

Comment: Yes, this is for Windows.